# How to translate "Keywords" to Spanish "Palabras claves"

Tags: babel, languages, lncs

I am writing a document in Spanish using the template [Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science (LNCS)](https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-lecture-notes-in-computer-science/kzwwpvhwnvfj)and I want to change the predefined 
 "Keywords" to the Spanish term "Palabras claves"

I am using:

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

but it doesn't  change "keywords" (although, for example, it changes "Abstract" to "Resumen").

This is how I am using the keywords:

```
\begin{abstract}
La gestión ....
\keywords{open data, open source}
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: It depends on how the class and packages define the `keywords` text. Could you please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How do you enter the keywords? E.g., via `\keywords{...}`? If so, which document class do you employ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to show how I am using the keywords and the basic template "LNCS" to give a MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `llncs` document class features the class options `deutsch` and `francais`, but nothing for spanish. :-(

I suggest you add the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\keywordname}{{\bfseries Palabras claves:}}
```

in the preamble. For further language customization possibilities, see lines 80 thru 114 of the file `llncs.cls`.

Comment: thanks! It works ok

Comment: In my case, as I have the abstract in three different languages and keywords at the end of each abstract, I had to add the instruction just before every keywords section of every language other than English: `\renewcommand{\keywords}{{\bfseries Paraules clau: }} \keywords{.......}`

Answer (score 4):

It's a good occasion for fixing bad coding by the `llncs` class.

```latex
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords}}
\addto{\captionsspanish}{\renewcommand{\keywordname}{Palabras claves}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\keywords}{\keywordname}{\textbf{\keywordname:}}{}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{El título}

\author{Autor}
\institute{Institución \\ \email{email}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{abstract}

\keywords{abc, def, ghi}

\section{Introducción}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Hardwiring `\bf` (yes, that's it!) in `\keywordname` is wrong to begin with. By also setting the name for English allows you to have bilingual keywords, in case of need. And is better programming anyway.

[image]